# Both my washing machine and shower have stopped working

Tags: plumbing

Specifically both seem to not be taking in any water.

The shower and washing machine both buzz and both sound like they are trying to take in water but nothing is happening, this happened at exactly the same time, however there has been no interruption to any of the other supplies.

The taps in both the kitchen (were the washing machine is) and the bathroom function as normal. Both hot and cold.

Anything I can do or look into?

Edit: The only things I know are the washing machine has old copper pipping with blue and red valves, the shower is a modern power shower, it has some kinda pressure light on it that normally changes colour when turned on, this doesn't happen but everything else lights up as normal.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please edit to add any information you can about your plumbing system and related fixtures. You haven't given much to work with.

Comment: Second welcome. Please think back to just before the washer and shower stopped working. Can you cite any out of the ordinary plumbing or water related events that happened in your abode? Replaced anything? City flushing water mains? Freezing outdoor temperature drop?

Comment: Also where in the world are you?

Comment: I am in the UK. Added the only information I know. There was a separate issue with a property underneath flooding which lead the landlord to send his plumber in to check everything, the issue later turned out to be nothing to do with this property, the issue started around then. I first the shower became a little intermittent over a two week period but after he visited it didn't work at all and the washing machine always worked until that point. I am not sure if he turned something off? But I can't see anything that would relate, he certainly didn't touch any of the actual plumbing.